# Почему нельзя "дружить кого-то"?

Tags: лексика

В теме "отношения" (на лекциях по математике) я привожу "любовь" как пример несимметричного отношения, а "дружбу" - симметричного. И действительно, "на белом свете есть безответная любовь", а вот про безответную дружбу что-то не слышно.

Это отражено и в управлении: *любить кого-то*, но *дружить - с кем-то*. Хотя в реальной жизни ничего симметричного не бывает, и вполне возможно, что в паре друзей один - "более друг" чем второй. И вообще может не считать себя другом.

Поэтому возникает вопрос: почему язык не предусмотрел глагола для односторонней дружбы? Может, вакантное место занимает какое-то другое слово? Та же любовь, интерес, внимание... Но все-таки "испытывать интерес", "заботится", "привлекать" и т.п. - не полные аналоги слову "дружить".

Получается, что дружба более эгоистична: без взаимности не жизнеспособна?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще-то обычно на вопросы, начинающиеся с "почему", я, не долго думая, отвечаю "потому что [таков язык]". Но в данном случае я смысл вопроса улавливаю. Вы пытаетесь провести параллель между реальными отношениями и их отображением в языке?  
Действительно, в русском языке под дружбой понимаются строго коммутативные отношения: если А дружит с Б, то Б дружит с А. Видимо, это заложено в русском (точнее - общеславянском) менталитете, поскольку в других известных мне языках это не так ярко выражено, хотя в общем-то в той или иной мере прослеживается везде. 
Бывет забавно смотреть на людей, впервые сталкивающтхся с системой "дружбы" на всяких там социальных сайтах. Они часто в толк взять не могут, что ***задружив*** (как вам словечко?) кого-то, они автоматически не становятся и другом своего нового друга. Кстати, вот тут бы понятие такой односторонней дружбы очень бы пригодилось...

Зато только в русском дружба родтвенна словам "другой", "друг друга", "дружина". 
Только назвать это эгоистичным я никак не могу. Как говориться, с "точностью до наоборот".

И ещё насчет "односторонней дружбы". Я думаю, нет слова только потому, что в реальности нет такого понятия, нет самих отношений. Если же вы сформулируете, что под этим понимать, полагаю, и слово подходящее найдётся. Не слово - так конструкция, термин. Может, сетевики-социальщики как раз и придумают. Пока что наиболее близким термином для таких сетевых отношений на мой взгляд является *доверие*. А доверяет Б, но Б не обязан доверять А.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, дружба в интернете все же не совсем односторонняя: один человек предлагает, а другой соглашается или нет.   
Да, в интернете дружба очень странная. Я бы, правда, предпочла в этом случае слово "интерес". Для чего я беру интернет-собеседника себе в друзья? Чтобы мне приходила информация о его действиях. Значит, он меня интересует.  
Хотя я долго не могла привыкнуть к этому и в душе считала себя виноватой, что не проявляю заботу о моих новоявленных "друзьях". Слава богу, здесь такого статуса нет.

Comment: По некотором размышлении предлагаю термин "испытывать дружеские чувства". Вот, например, я явно испытываю к @behemothus дружеские чувства (как и многие другие участники), но совсем не рассчитываю на взаимность (зачем оно мне?).  
Конечно, настоящая дружба не сводится к чувствам, но предполагает действия. Но, может, "сопротивление" со стороны второго участника и делает такие действия невозможными?

Comment: >Один человек предлагает, а другой соглашается или нет  

Ой, нет... Во всяком случае - далеко не "во всем интернете". Сейчас на большинстве так называемых социальных ресурсов от такой взаимности отказались.



Comment: Это для меня новость... Впрочем, я не посещаю такие места, хотя зарегистрирована во многих. Отчасти в ответ на предложения разных знакомых (которые, возможно посылали не они, а система)

Comment: Ну я тоже не могу сказать, что много где сейчас бываю, но я еще и на "мнение общественности" ориентируюсь. Да оно и логично в общем-то. Ведь понятие сетевой дружбы свелось к вопросам доступа к личной информации и подписке на новости, исходящие от друзей. Ну и зачем мне получать ежедневные рассылки от Имярекова только потому, что он хочет читать мои?   
Там, где эти отношения трактуют шире, вполне возможно и сохранение старого, взаимного формата "дружбы".

Comment: behemothus! Я с какого боку в Вашем диалоге? Надеюсь, это опечатка.

Comment: Да, конечно, простите. Подвела меня манера ники копировать.
Но Вы, надеюсь, поняли сразу.